# How to make the text in beamer navigation bars shorter?

Tags: beamer, navigation

Now, I am curious about using `beamer` to make slides, but the title for each section is several words, then with several sections, so that the navigation bar does not look well.

I want to just use one or two words instead of the total name for each section;

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Use the optional argument for the sectional units: `\section[Two words]{A title with more words}` (compile twice to see the change).

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional argument for the sectional units, as in

```
\section[Two words]{A title with more words}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\section[Shorter title]{A section with an extremely long title and some more words for the example}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection[Another shorter title]{A subsection with an extremely long title and some more words for the example}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting navigation bar:

[image]